# Conditional Unique in MySql DB and EF Core

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have a table dealers which has column token(need to be unique) and has isTokenActive(bool).
I was wandering if there is a way to add unique constraint on a token column but only if there is another row that has same token and isTokenActive is set to 1. If there is a row with same token and isTokenActive is set to 0 that is a valid case too.

Basically I want to allow this

```
  id |   Token    |  isTokenActive   |
--------------------------------------
  1  |    ABC     |      0           |
  2  |    ABC     |      1           |
```

And this

```
  id |   Token    |  isTokenActive   |
--------------------------------------
  1  |    ABC     |      0           |
  2  |    ABC     |      0           |
```

But not this

```
  id |   Token    |  isTokenActive   |
--------------------------------------
  1  |    ABC     |      1           |
  2  |    ABC     |      1           |
```

And it would be great if it is possible to do it code first with EF Core.

Comment: You can do it easily by unique index while using NULL instead of zero.

Comment: Yes, but that seems little hacky since I need to use it through all database where nothing is getting deleted. Can you suggest any other solution ? Thanks !